# Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class CampaignService does not exist' in Google Adword API (with custom PHP)

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

I am new in Google Adword API. I am using Google Adword API with Custom PHP.
After Oauth when I get Campaign it show me an error of

> Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException'.

My code is

```
namespace Google\AdsApi\AdWords;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

use Google\Auth\OAuth2;

session_start();

$oauth2 = new OAuth2([
    'authorizationUri' => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth',
    'tokenCredentialUri' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    'redirectUri' => 'http://mysitename/adwords/googleadwordapi/',
    'clientId' => 'xxxx',
    'clientSecret' => 'xxxx',
    'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'
]); 

if (!isset($_GET['code']))
{

  $oauth2->setState(sha1(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1024)));
  $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $oauth2->getState();


  $config = [

    'access_type' => 'online'
  ];
  header('Location: ' . $oauth2->buildFullAuthorizationUri($config));
  exit;
}
 elseif (empty($_GET['state'])
    || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
  exit('Invalid state.');
} else {
  $oauth2->setCode($_GET['code']);
   $authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();


  $access_token = $authToken['access_token'];
$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())
        ->fromFile()
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oauth2)
        ->build();


$adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();


$campaignService = $adWordsServices->get($session, 'CampaignService', 'v201609', 'cm');

}
```

it show an error

> "Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class CampaignService does not exist'"

I check class CampaignService and it is present in desire location.

Comment: I am not using Laravel I am using simple php

Comment: This is the link of Google Client (Adword) API that I am using https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib